# How Do I Make A Third-Party Form Position Itself At The Bottom Of My Page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, ninja-forms

I am building a webpage using the Themify-Ultra Theme. I have installed a plugin called Ninja Forms to handle a contact form I need installed. The form will not display using the widgit builder but will display using a shortcode inside the editor.

The problem is that I have content that needs to be displayed before my contact form. I cannot figure out a way to make the plugin appear at the bottom of the page. I would work if the form appeared as a widget but it does not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should create Themify-Ultra child theme and then add  shortcode in footer.php. it will be display in all pages and post

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how this would help? I would like to display this contact form only on one page.

Comment: All I want to do is add the plugin to my page in a custom position. Not all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue. I was able to add the form as a footer widget. Thanks guys.